# how to kill specific GNOME shell extension in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 using Wayland session. I installed many extensions trough **Ubuntu Software** > **Add-ons** > **Shell Extensions** to support my daily activities,

but I want to kill some of them because they sometimes slow down the computer, especially when I work with huge programs at the same time.

Is there a way to kill some specific extensions in Gnome Shell temporarily (just for the current session)?

Comment: I am not sure about that method to install extension, I usually install them from the website through the browser. To disable them I then go to Gnome Tweak > Extensions and I disable what I do not want (see https://imgur.com/rt9TB7o for a screenshot)

Comment: Thanks. But, I thought 'disable' option will affect the next login session.

Comment: Yes it will, but it's easier to disable/enable them than uninstall/install via the software center...

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, I'm not aware that any GNOME extensions seriously slow down the computer.

However...

Using standard Ubuntu tools, use Firefox (or other web browser) and go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. There you can enable or disable individual extensions at will.

To complete the task, restart GNOME Shell with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>.

You can also use `GNOME Tweaks` (gnome-tweaks) to do the same thing (except for the GNOME Shell restart).

Comment: I don't know if it doesn't happen to you. But, they really slow my computer down sometimes. I installed more than 10 extensions, maybe not all of them, but some of them do it, and I don't know exactly which ones. I appreciate your answer, also like @dadexix86 commented on my question. Thanks for it. But I wonder if there is a way to just kill it using command line, because if we disable it, it will affect to the next login session and I want to kill it just for the current session. And btw, restart GNOME shell using that shortcut is not available on Wayland session.

Comment: @fsevenm have you considered trying to run without Wayland, and seeing how it effects your perceived speed?

Comment: I'll report if I get it better.

Comment: @fsevenm status please...

Comment: I still don't find a way to do jt.

Comment: @fsevenm  Did you try running without Wayland? Just a standard GNOME session?

Comment: For some reason, I cannot switch to another desktop session e.g. Xorg. Each time I tried, it failed. So for now, I only disable the extensions

Comment: @fsevenm In the `terminal` you can try using the `debsums` command to check some of your OS components. See `man debsums` for more info.

Comment: I have an extension that on disabling it will fail and remain there, til now it got 5 instances running... the trick was to restart gnome, thx!